# Returning SimpleXML object in class constructor - why does it not work?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Hey, I have a small test case set up as following:

```
class T {
    public function __construct(){
        $obj = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents('vote.xml'));
        return $obj;
    }
}

$vv=new T;
var_dump($vv);
```

The dump of `$vv` equals, in this case, `object(T)#1 (0) { }` - in other words, **not the expected output**

When I return the object in a separate function, though, like this:

```
class T {
    public function stackOverflow(){
        $obj = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents('vote.xml')); // or simplexml_load_file
        return $obj;
    }
}

$vv=new T;
$vv = $vv->stackOverflow();
var_dump($vv);
```

output is as expected (the object containing contents of 'vote.xml', tags and attributes). Why can I not return the object inside of the constructor? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor will only ever return a reference to the newly created object.  This is intentional -- how else would you get a reference to the new object?

You could, however, create an object property in your constructor and then access it from outside.  This would mean that you would create the object during the constructor process, so it would be done at the right time and, what's more, could be guaranteed to be done.

```
class T {
    public $sxml;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->sxml = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents('vote.xml'));
    }
}

$vv=new T;
var_dump($vv->sxml);
```

Of course, if you don't *need* the reference to the new object, you could use a static method instead and never use the constructor:

```
class T {
    public static function sxml() {
        return new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents('vote.xml'));
    }
}
```